# SailPoint Policy - Using a script to check user's department

Tags: java, beanshell, identity-management, sailpoint

I was trying this, and it works only if the "username" is contained on Traka, however if for instance "adm_username" is there, then ti wouldn't work.

I do not know whether this is even technically possible, since sailpoint seems to be grabbing the identity directly, each time it is iterating through a search.

```
import sailpoint.object.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;


PolicyViolation polVil = null;

if (identity != null) {
    String identityName = identity.getName();

    // Check if the identity has the Traka application entitlement
    boolean hasTrakaEntitlement = false;
    List<Link> links = identity.getLinks();
    for (Link link : links) {
        if (link.getApplicationName().equalsIgnoreCase("Traka")) {
            hasTrakaEntitlement = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    // Check if the identity's department is not "IAM"
    boolean hasNonIAMDepartment = false;
    if (identity.getLinks() != null) {
        for (Link link : identity.getLinks()) {
            String department = (String) link.getAttribute("Department");
            if (department != null && !department.equalsIgnoreCase("IAM")) {
                hasNonIAMDepartment = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // If the identity has the Traka application entitlement and non-IAM department, create a policy violation
    if (hasTrakaEntitlement && hasNonIAMDepartment) {
        polVil = new PolicyViolation();
        polVil.setActive(true);
        polVil.setIdentity(identity);
        polVil.setPolicy(policy);
        polVil.setDescription("Identity has the Traka application entitlement and non-IAM department.");
    } else {

    }
}

return polVil;
```